# I am getting no sound at all when playing songs?

Tags: windows-10

The volume level of the speakers has been correctly set.  I attempted to play songs.  I did not get any sound at all.  However, the song is playing.  But there is no sound at all. The audio drivers were updated.  But there is no use.

Comment: What are you using to play songs? What audio source? Do other sources work? We need more information to be able to answer your question.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'm using default audio player(Windows Media Player) no other sources work too. Thank you

Comment: are your speakers plugged in and the default device set correctly?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I have inbuilt speakers in my desktop computer i.e it an all in one P.C

Comment: Was this working recently? You said the audio drivers were updated. Did it work before that? Have you attempted to roll back the drivers to see if that resolves it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Windows volume is turned up with the icon in the bottom-right. Also make sure the application which is playing the song has it's volume turned up. Also make sure your speakers are plugged into the computer properly. If it's not working after attempting those steps, right-click the audio icon in the bottom-right and open your volume mixer. When the song is playing, you should see the bar next to "speaker" going up and down. If it's doing that, then it should be outputting audio.

Comment: Like you said everything is popping-up but I can here no sound. I have even tried updating the drivers, disable and re-enable the speakers etc., and etc.,

Comment: Just to clarify, you saw a bar moving up and down indicating sound output, correct? Your speakers should be plugged in (usually) to the green headphone-style plug.

Comment: Yes and I'm getting no sound at all from any source. I didn't even hear any Message Beeps

Comment: If everything is plugged in correctly, we'll need some hardware information. Do you know which components your computer has or what model your computer is?

Comment: I went to device manager and updated all the drives for audio devices and speakers. I ran the test sound and my P.C informs sound is playing but I cannot here any sound. I ran the troubleshooter and found generic audio driver is missing and it is annoying because when I tried to fix it my windows shows the same again and again

Comment: What kind of computer do you have?

Comment: It is Dell All in one P.C with Windows 10. Speakers, CPU are inbuilt inside the monitor

Comment: I took a few guesses and wound up here. Try downloading [this](http://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER03574594M/1/Audio_Driver_7776F_WN32_6.0.1.7737_A04.EXE) audio driver. Also make sure you don't have any headphones plugged in.

Comment: You can go [here](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-20-3052-aio/drivers) and click "View a different product" and "Detect Product". Just to make sure it's the right one.